# Implementing adjacency matrices (or adjacency lists) in C#

Tags: c#, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I am producing some simple network drawing software in C# (I shall write 'network' rather than 'graph' for clarity). Networks may eventually have multiple directed edges between some vertices/nodes. I have designed the data structure for this software as follows:

- Each node and edge has a corresponding 'interactible' object determining the visualisation and processing inputs such as clicks targeted at these visible objects. These objects may store any amount of data about the respective objects that I choose, and for now they contain the endpoints of the edges, for example, as well as an integer identifier for each object.
- Nodes (and edges between them) are divided into connected components. I want to implement routines which merge these components upon addition of edges and detect disconnectedness when edges or nodes are deleted.
- The overall data for the network *which shall for now simply record the number of edges between each pair of nodes, ignoring direction* is to be represented in an instance of an `INetwork` interface, which contains such routines as those for adding and removing nodes and edges, identifying the neighbours of a vertex, and so on.

My question, then, is how to actually implement this `IMatrix` interface. The implementation can be made to vary with the sparseness of the graph, but I would like to know in terms of memory, processing speed etc what would be most efficient.

More precisely, I am aware that I could just produce an adjacency matrix for each component, or similarly an adjacency list, but *which types are best suited to these roles in C#*, bearing in mind that my nodes have integer identifiers which I would expect are best left constant throughout?

Would `Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,int>>` ever be a good way of implementing an adjacency count so as to be able to remove entries efficiently? Would a large 2-dimensional array work given the node indexing? If I instead store a matrix as a 1-dim'l array, say as an `int[]` with some methods for treating this as a 2- or 3-dimensional array, would this be better in any meaningful way?

Of course, there are pros and cons to every implementation, but I expect the most taxing routine will always be the one that checks whether the removal of an edge has resulted in the network becoming disconnected. Thus I want whatever implementation I use to be able to quickly check:

1. Whether a removed edge was the last edge between its pair of vertices.
2. If so, to be able to quickly identify the neighbours of each node successively so as to identify which nodes lie in which of the resulting components.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions. In case anyone wonders, the choice of C# was because of my reliance on the Unity game-making engine for its rendering and (possibly, later on) physics capabilities.

Comment: To the person that keeps editing my question by replacing the British English spelling with American English spelling and saying they are correcting spelling errors, please stop. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23872/335667

Comment: If I had under ~1000 nodes, I would just stick with Lists until I knew for sure this was the bottleneck in my code.    Personally, I am so lazy that I tend to use linq select clauses instead of indexing into dictionary.  If this was in a tight innner loop, I would try to keep memory allocation and garbage collection to a minimum.  And I feel that it is easier to reason about allocation and GC if I am just using 1D arrays.